# iPad UI element question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what UI elements to I need to create a boxed section like the related section on this page with a 3px wide border and a light grey background? UILabels and what else? are UILabels clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a UIButton with a custom background image for a single link.

If you wanted more than one link you could use a 9 slice UIImage for the background and UIButtons for each item with no background image set?

Or a UIView for the background with the border with and color set for it's [layer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CALayer) if you just want a very simple rectangular grey border? i.e.

```
[[[self view] layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor greyColor] CGColor]];
```

Or, you could use a UIWebView styling it with CSS with each line a href, grabbing the links in the UIWebView's delegate with a custom URL format for each link.

Personally, I'd use the UIView's layer borderColor properties etc to style a background and then use UIButtons for each link, then use a UIImage if I needed the background to be more complicated. I find a web view overkill for something like this.